# Giving a space between delimiter

Tags: php

I have a string which need to give a space between delimiters, for example :

`Oceans and lakes have much in common,but they are also quite different.`

The Expected Output should be as below:

`Oceans and lakes have much in common , but they are also quite different .`

I have tried with preg_replace and I only can give a space in next char.

Here is my code :

`$string = "Oceans and lakes have much in common,but they are also quite different."`
`$string = preg_replace('/([\.,\?\!\:])/',"\\1 ",$string);`

And the output :

`Oceans and lakes have much in common, but they are also quite different.`

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: can you please add more code to your question?

Comment: code added @Farini

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a space before the `\\1` reference in the replacement (second argument)

`$string = preg_replace('/([\.,\?\!\:])/'," \\1 ",$string);`

Answer (score 1):

Try `preg_replace('/([\.\?\!\:])/'\ \,\ \"\\1 ",$string);` Not sure about php but in bash you have to escape white spaces.